# Chef knife create failing to create an API user

Tags: chef-infra, knife

It seems like an easy thing to fix but I've just can't get knife to create a new user for me. I'm user chef-server with the management dashboard. I created an admin user with the initial command `knife configure --initial` with the root user. Now I'm trying to create an api user for a local user named "myuser" for example.

So, I do this:

```
myuser@chefserver:~$ knife configure --initial
Overwrite /home/myuser/.chef/knife.rb? (Y/N)y
Please enter the chef server URL: [https://chefserver:443] 
Please enter a name for the new user: [myuser]
Please enter the existing admin name: [admin]
Please enter the location of the existing admin's private key: [/etc/chef-server/admin.pem] 
Please enter the validation clientname: [chef-validator] 
Please enter the location of the validation key: [/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem] 
Please enter the path to a chef repository (or leave blank): 
Creating initial API user...
Please enter a password for the new user: 
ERROR: The data in your request was invalid
Response: Field 'display_name' missing
```

Why is it failing to create an API user?

Comment: By any chance are you trying to use the new Chef Server 12 release candidate?

Comment: I'm using: chef-server-core_12.0.0-rc.4-1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`knife configure` does not work with Chef Server 12 at this time. The easiest way to do the initial setup for Chef Server 12 is to use the premium WebUI feature. This is free for up to 25 nodes, otherwise you should check with Chef Software for pricing. You can do the setup using the command-line tools but it is undocumented at this time and not really viable for most people.

Comment: Thanks! I have the web interface, reports, analytics, all set up through the CLI. I was getting confused about using knife as opposed to chef-server-ctl. Is it just me or is opscode documentation in a state of flux right now? I can't find a solid article for installing Chef Server 12 + node config + workstation setup

Comment: It is a release candidate in name only, it should really just be called a beta. I'm still hopeful that the UX will improve before release, but now it is definitely rough. As it stands, the replacement for `knife configure` is the Starter Kit link you'll see in the Organization config screen. I'm a tad biased since I wrote that system, but I think it is much better than the old method :)

Comment: You can also use the chef-server-ctl tool on the Chef Server 12 system itself to create users. That is the replacement for "knife configure".

Comment: Found this page while having the same problem. The documentation for Chef 12 is utterly abysmal. Instructions for workstation setup basically don't exist right now.

Comment: Yes, Chef 12 is an early pre-release and should only be used if you are comfortable testing unreleased software.

Comment: I have the latest version which is now touted as the official release. Still the EXACT same behavior. This is ridiculous. I'll try the instructions here and get back with results. Otherwise I'm switching back to 11. What a waste of time.   http://docs.chef.io/client/install_workstation.html

Comment: @einarc There have indeed been no changes. You need to build your config via the Web UI or the chef-server-ctl tool.

Comment: @coderanger. My results are below. I succeeded with knife configure. The detail though was to avoid using the init command and pass in the arguments with flags instead. Web ui works as well.

Comment: @coderanger One more thing I forgot to mention is that the master input is not just the FQDN of the master server but the entire path to the organization. Just like you see it on the WEB UI. More details below.

Answer (score 0):

The comment below assumes you have already created an organization and a user for that organization in the master server. And that you copied over the user and organization .pem keys to your local workstation and are now ready to set the workstation.

The user is admin and the organization is bwengineering, the user must belong to the organization. The master server's FQDN is master.dev

Also notice that you need to bring over the master crt files using this:

```
knife ssl fetch https://master.dev
```

Make sure to cd into the chef-repo folder to do all this.

In Chef 12 **DO NOT** use `knife configure --initial`. Instead pass in the arguments as flags. Like this:

```
knife configure -s https://master.dev/organizations/bwengineering/ -r ~/chef-repo --admin-client-key ~/chef-repo/.chef/admin.pem --admin-client-name admin -c ~/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb --validation-client-name bwengineering-validator --validation-key ~/chef-repo/.chef/chef-validator.pem
```

After this export the chefdk binaries to your .bash_profile and THEN bootstrap your nodes. How to do the latter depends on your node configuration. If you can log in as root then use that directly, otherwise use the --sudo flag.

Comment: This is still not the correct solution, you should not use this. Please remove this answer. The correct solution is above, use the starter kit generated by the web UI or make your knife.rb from scratch.

Comment: @coderanger: Thank You! I'd like to learn what the difference is between creating a knife.rb using knife configure like this and creating it from scratch in a text editor. What does it do to the system? Are you worried about the API user and key? Thanks.

Comment: Because the command is deprecated and really doesn't get you much. You can just fill in this template https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/configure.rb#L78-L85 yourself. There is no reason to confuse people by using the command when all it does is write that text file now.

Comment: @coderanger. The problem is I think that there's no official Chef Ops documentation that says the command is deprecated and to go the alternative routes. While essentially I agree with you (knife doesn't work the way it's documented with Chef 2) people like myself may still try to use it because Chef's own documentation says it still does. I simply found a method to use it. If letting the command die is the real option then Chef Ops NEEDS to do that in their documentation as well. I haven't found any document on Chef's website that says knife configure --initial is deprecated.

Comment: At that's why I'm not using Chef in its master/node/workstation configuration.